# BizTalk managing it's own receive ports

Tags: powershell, port, biztalk, automatic-updates

I have a request to create an orchestration that would receive notification from an application directing the BizTalk server to change state.  State may be Live, Disaster Recovery, or Fail Over.  When BizTalk would receive this notification, it would then enable and disabled receive locations.

We have looked into powershell scripts that work but need special permissions given to the process that executes these scripts.

Is there any internal mechanism to BizTalk which will provide me the functionality I want without having to look into managing my powershell script with a specified user?  Is there a better way of handling this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no 'special' internal API to manage a BizTalk Group that bypasses the security layer.

Management of BizTalk is through (mostly) WMI and ExplorerOM and the permissions are granted through membership on one of the Administrative groups.  A BizTalk host is subject to the same rules as you or me.

My recommendation would be to define a new service account that has BizTalk Operators membership for the Group.  Create a new Host/Hose Instance that uses this service account.

That Host would run only your Admin Orchestrations, nothing else.

If you choose this route, I'd also recommend doing WMI directly in C#, no PowerShell.  It's a cleaner experiance.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  We were trying to find a way other than having the orchestration host instance have admin rights.  We might try implementing the receive location enable and disable performed by an external EXE that we would be run with admin rights.  This way we don't change our host instances and we can still have the access we are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Sure, you could do that in a Windows Service or IIS app, but either way, some process needs to run with Admin for the BizTalk group so Host Instance/Service/asmx are really just different management experiences.